# Appending rows using a function doesn't save rows

Tags: python, pandas, function, append

I am trying to append rows that run through a function weighted_rows. However it only prints the first row despite there being over 1000 in df.

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    weighted_t = weighted_df.append(weighted_rows(i), ignore_index=True)
```

This for loop only print the first row of df that has gone through the function, whereas I want it to append every other row (1000 or so) and output them all as a big dataframe. Is there something I need to add to my function? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove `[0]` This is the index of the first element.

Comment: What is the output of `weighted_rows(i)`? The first parameter of the `append` function is another DataFrame or Series

Comment: weighted_rows outputs a row, so weighted_rows(6) for example gives a single row with index 6

Answer (score 0):

I was making a simple mistake. I wasn't appending to the data frame I had intended, but rather the new one called weighted_t, which meant the data frame was not saving. This is the simple fix. Thanks for everyone who tried to help.

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    weighted_df = weighted_df.append(weighted_rows(i), ignore_index=True)
```